# How to select column in MySQL table and get value with PHP mysql_result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tables illustrated below

```
//reference type table
+---+-----------+---------+
|ID |Article_ID |Ref_Types|
+---+-----------+---------+
| 1 | 1         | article |
| 2 | 1         | book    |
| 3 | 1         | article |
| 4 | 1         | article |
| 5 | 2         | book    |
+---+-----------+---------+
//book references table
+---+-----------+--------+
|ID |Article_ID |Title   |
+---+-----------+--------+
| 1 | 1         | book1  |
| 2 | 1         | book2  |
| 3 | 2         | book3  |
| 4 | 2         | book4  |
| 5 | 2         | book5  |
+---+-----------+--------+
//article references table
+---+-----------+-----------+
|ID |Article_ID |Title      |
+---+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | 1         | article1  |
| 2 | 1         | article2  |
| 3 | 2         | article3  |
| 4 | 2         | article4  |
| 5 | 2         | article5  |
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

1. I have to look into first table and check the reference, of which type it is;
2. for each reference type, I have get reference table from related table
3. I have to output in order, as shown in table one.

#### 1:

```
$data=array();
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reftypes 
WHERE Article_ID=1 ORDER BY ID ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $data[]=$row[2]; // i store in an array so that i can use later..
     }
```

#### 2:

```
foreach ($data as $ref) {
$counter=1;
switch ($ref) {
case "article":
 $sqlarticle= mysql_query("SELECT Title 
FROM book WHERE Article_ID=1 ORDER BY ID ASC");
echo mysql_result($sqlarticle, $counter); //i want to get only one out of book table
$counter++;
break;
...
...
```

But `$sqlarticle` does not seem to work.

I want to display as:

```
+-----------+----------+
|Article_ID |Reference |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | article1 |
| 1         | book1    |
| 1         | article2 |
| 1         | article3 |
+-----------+----------+
```

I know it is a long question and for experts or experienced people it is very trivial, but that is where I'm stuck.

Comment: is this PHP? please tag properly.

Comment: What is the `reference_type` table meant for? You really should normalize you database to get around those problems.

Comment: hi feeela, because when user adds new reference, first he chooses of which type it is. this is needed because article and book has different attributes..

Comment: why mysql_result? why can't you use familiar mysql_fetch_array instead?

Comment: you want a strange result, since for article id=1 you have book1, book2, article1, article2.

Comment: @vulkanino, i do want the order that is present in reference_type table..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    reftypes R
WHERE 
    Article_ID=your_id 
LEFT JOIN books B ON (B.Article_ID = R.Article_ID AND R.Ref_Types = 'book')
LEFT JOIN articles A ON (A.Article_ID = R.Article_ID AND R.Ref_Types = 'article')
ORDER BY
    R.id ASC;
```

Even if the database is wrongly modeled, I think.

What about the followin model instead?

[image: alternative model]

Comment: That's really "raw". You should explain what "join" is !

Comment: @YvesMartin "should"? Is it a barrack here and you are commander? If not - change the tone please.  BTW, you are welcome to explain  whatever you find necessary yourself.

Comment: Sorry - I mean "may" - I was writing an answer explaining joint and gave up when I saw the "first version" of your answer... Such a request may not be understood by a SQL newbie. So my comment.

Answer (score 0):

""although especially question owners should respect any kind of effort and input, -i am thankful- i can not understand why some people try to think of question's holder as well-informed or experienced as themselves, or worse comment from higher level. ""

anyway, my question was about to get values one by one, here is how i did it;

```
$data=array();
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reftypes 
WHERE Article_ID=1 ORDER BY ID ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $data[]=$row[2]; // i store in an array so that i can use later..
     }
$articlecount=0;
$bookcount=0;
foreach ($data as $value) {
       switch ($value) {
         case "article":
           $sqlarticle=mysql_query("SELECT RefArticleTitle 
                   FROM ref_article 
                   WHERE $article_ID=Article_ID 
                   ORDER BY ID ASC");
           $articles=  mysql_result($sqlarticle, $articlecount);
           echo $articles;
           echo "\n";
           $articlecount++;
           break;
           case "book":
           $sqlbook=mysql_query("SELECT RefBookName 
                   FROM ref_book 
                   WHERE $article_ID=Article_ID 
                   ORDER BY ID ASC");
           $books=  mysql_result($sqlbook, $bookcount);
           echo $books;
           echo "\n";
           $bookcount++;
           break;
...
...
```

as a result, i got what i required..

```
+-----------+----------+
|Article_ID |Reference |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | article1 |
| 1         | book1    |
| 1         | article2 |
| 1         | article3 |
+-----------+----------+
```

thanks to whoever interested in the topic..

Answer (score -1):

```
      $result=mysqli_query("select ref_types from reference type");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $table=$row[0];
    $result1=mysqli_query("select * from $table");
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {
        var_dump($row1);
        }
}
```

Comment: and how do you connect the tables?